# Keep a running total in Repeater control, trying to modify existing code

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, repeater

I have a script that keeps running totals as values are being entered into a GridView form control.

This works great.
Below is the code:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('[id*=txttaxpayerret]').keyup(function () {
                totalcalculate();
            });
            window.onload = totalcalculate();
            function totalcalculate() {
                var total = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < $('.txttaxpayerret').length; i++) {
                    var temp = $('.txttaxpayerret')[i].value;
                    temp != "" ? temp : temp = 0;
                    total = parseFloat(temp) + parseFloat(total);
                    $('[id*=lblTotal]').html(total);
                }
            }
        });
 </script>
<asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

we recently switched from GridView control to Repeater and since then, the code stopped worked working.

I have been trying to modify to work with Repeater control but to no avail.

Any ideas how to get this code to continue to keep a running to total user's entry as they are being entered?

llblTotal is outside the Repeater control.

However, txttaxpayerret is inside the Repeater control

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txttaxpayerret" runat="server" Width="280px"></asp:TextBox>
```

**UPDATED:**

```
         <asp:Repeater ID="rptAircraft" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                  <tr>
                    <td>
                         <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="280px" Text='<%#Eval("taxpayerret") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </td>
                </tr>
             </ItemTemplate>
           </asp:Repeater>
          <tr>
            <td>
                 <asp:TextBox ID="txttaxpayerret"  CssClass="clsTxtToCalculate" runat="server" Width="280px"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
          </tr>
         </table>
         asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Width="70px" Text="Add More" onclick="btnAdd_Click" />
         <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

UPDATED:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(function () {
        $('body').on('keyup', '.taxInput', function (e) {
            totalcalculate();
        });
        window.onload = totalcalculate();
        function totalcalculate() {
            var total = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < $('.taxInput').length; i++) {
                var temp = $('.taxInput')[i].value;
                temp != "" ? temp : temp = 0;
                total = parseFloat(temp) + parseFloat(total);
                $('[id*=lblTotal]').html(total);
            }
        }
});

  <table border="1" style="width:50%;text-align:center">
<tr>
<td style="width:100%;vertical-align: text-top;">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
 <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upPanael" runat="server">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <div><div>
        <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <th>
                    AIRCRAFT REGISTRATION #:
                </th>
                <th>
                    RETURNED VALUE<br /> 
                </th>
                <th>
                    FOR TAX OFFICE USE ONLY<br />
                </th>
                <th>&nbsp;</th>
            </tr>
             <asp:Repeater ID="rptAircraft" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                      <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Width="530px" Text='<%#Eval("boatregNum") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                             <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" Width="280px" Text='<%#Eval("taxpayerret") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Width="256px" Text='<%#Eval("fortaxofficeonly") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                        <td>&nbsp;</td>
                    </tr>
                 </ItemTemplate>
               </asp:Repeater>
              <tr>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtboatregNum" runat="server" Width="530px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                     <asp:TextBox ID="txttaxpayerret"  CssClass="taxInput" runat="server" Width="280px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtfortaxofficeonly" runat="server" Width="256px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td style="white-space:nowrap;">
                   <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Width="70px" Text="Add New" onclick="btnAdd_Click" />
                   <asp:Button ID="btnDelete" runat="server" Width="70px" Text="Remove" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    </div>
   </ContentTemplate>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
   </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <table border="1" style="width: 87%; text-align: center">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 43.6%;">
            TOTAL&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;>
        </td>
        <td style="width: 23.2%;">
            <asp:Label ID="lblTotal" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td class="auto-style4">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

protected void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtAircraft = new DataTable();
    dtAircraft = GetAircraftInfo();

    if (ViewState["AircraftTable"] != null)
    {
        dtAircraft = (DataTable)ViewState["AircraftTable"];


        rptAircraft.DataSource = dtAircraft;
        rptAircraft.DataBind();
        rptAircraft.Visible = true;
    }
    else
    {
        rptAircraft.DataSource = null;
        rptAircraft.DataBind();
        rptAircraft.Visible = false;
    }
    txtboatregNum.Text = string.Empty;
    txttaxpayerret.Text = string.Empty;
    txtfortaxofficeonly.Text = string.Empty;
}

private DataTable GetAircraftInfo()
{

    DataTable dtAircraft = null;
    if (ViewState["RowNumber"] != null)
    {
        int RowNumber = Convert.ToInt32((ViewState["RowNumber"]));
        RowNumber++;
        ViewState["RowNumber"] = RowNumber;
    }
    else
    {
        ViewState["RowNumber"] = 1;
    }

    if (ViewState["AircraftTable"] == null)
    {
        dtAircraft = new DataTable("AircraftTable");
        dtAircraft.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(int)));
        dtAircraft.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("boatregNum", typeof(string)));
        dtAircraft.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("taxpayerret", typeof(string)));
        dtAircraft.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("fortaxofficeonly", typeof(string)));

        ViewState["AircraftTable"] = dtAircraft;
    }
    else
    {
        dtAircraft = (DataTable)ViewState["AircraftTable"];
    }
    DataRow dtRow = dtAircraft.NewRow();

    dtRow["RowNumber"] = Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["RowNumber"]);
    dtRow["boatregNum"] = txtboatregNum.Text.Trim();
    dtRow["taxpayerret"] = txttaxpayerret.Text.Trim();
    dtRow["fortaxofficeonly"] = txtfortaxofficeonly.Text.Trim();
    dtAircraft.Rows.Add(dtRow);
    ViewState["AircraftTable"] = dtAircraft;
    return dtAircraft;
}
```

Comment: Could you share the code in btnAdd_Click?

Comment: Ok I have updated the code, including the markup - relevant working version.

Thanks again for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do this `$('.txttaxpayerret')` you're trying to get an input with a class named `txttaxpayerret` (Reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors)

You can fix this by adding a class to your input.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txttaxpayerret" CssClass="taxInput" runat="server" Width="280px"></asp:TextBox>
```

And then you can use that class as a selector:

```
   $(function () {
        $('body').on('keyup', '.taxInput', function (e) {
            totalcalculate();
        });
        window.onload = totalcalculate();
        function totalcalculate() {
            var total = 0;
            for (var i = 0; i < $('.taxInput').length; i++) {
                var temp = $('.taxInput')[i].value;
                temp != "" ? temp : temp = 0;
                total = parseFloat(temp) + parseFloat(total);
                $('[id*=lblTotal]').html(total);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks very much for your response. Your solution works until I add another row. In other words, users can enter value, then click to add another row so they can enter additional values. That's where your solution is failing. It calculates correctly the first value but ignores any additional values.

VDWWD, your solution didn't do anything when I tried it.

Thanks to both for your assistance.

CORRECTION: VDWWD, yours does exactly what kblok's solution does as scribed. Sorry about that error in posting.

Comment: @Kenny I changed the recipe `$('body').on('keyup', '.taxInput', function (e) {`

Comment: @kblob, thank you again but it is still not working correctly.

Right now, it displays that last entered value.

For instance, if you enter 4 on the original row, add another row and enter 6, what we are expecting the running total to be is 10. Instead, it displays the last entered value, in this case 6.

Comment: @Kenny how are you adding another row? Is the class `taxInput` present in the added field?

Comment: @Kenny the javascript should work, this fiddle is working https://jsfiddle.net/ax8Le8d9/

Comment: I am dynamically adding rows. Please see updated code above. It is not the working code but just an example of what I am doing.

So, user enters value into the default cell for txttaxpayerret then clicks the Add More button to add another cell to enter another value into.

Meanwhile, the total of what is entered into however many rows for the same txttaxpayerret is entered into the lblTotal ID control.

Comment: @Kenny you nee to add the `CssClass="taxInput"` in the `TextBox2` you have in the repeater, that's all, I tested that locally.

Comment: @kblok, I could have sworn I did that before.

I did that again and it is working flawlessly.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The ID's of the TextBox inside the Repeater contol get's renamed. It becomes something like `Repeater1_txttaxpayerret`. So it is better to bind to a class name or to the input type of `text`.

Bind by `class`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txttaxpayerret" CssClass="txttaxpayerret" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

$('.txttaxpayerret').keyup(function () {
    totalcalculate();
});
```

Or wrap the repeater with a div with a known ID and loop the inputs.

```
<div id="myRepeater">
    <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txttaxpayerret" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</div>

$('#myRepeater input[type="text"]').keyup(function () {
    totalcalculate();
});
```

Now you have correctly bound the `keyup` function. Now you can loop them with `each` and get their values.

```
function totalcalculate() {
    var total = 0;
    $('#myRepeater input[type="text"]').each(function () {
        if ($(this).val() != "") {
            total += parseFloat($(this).val());
        }
    });
    $("#<%= lblTotal.ClientID %>").text(total);
}

// or use $('.txttaxpayerret').each
```